# How to find a smooth solution - initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the initial value problem:

y''+4y=f(t) y(0)=1, y'(0)=0

f(t) = 1-t on [0,1]

t-1 on [1,2]

And f(x) is a periodic function, and f (t+2) =f (t) for all t

So I solve it for [0,1] and for [1,2] and got:

y1 = Acos(2t) + Bsin(2t) + 0.25 - 0.25t on [0,1]
And from the initial condition I found A and B:
A=3/4
B=2/4

y2= Ccos(2t) + Dsin(2t) - 0.25 + 0.25t on [1,2]

So, first - how do I find C, D?

The solution has to be smooth (smooth function) - so I need: y1(1)=y2(1) and also y1'(1)=y2'(1)

So If I take y1 (1) =y2 (1) I get that

A=C=3/4

B=D=2/4

But I don't know how to prove y1'(1)=y2'(1).

Please help :)

Thank you

Comment: Take the derivative, plug in $1$.

Answer (score 2):

You should use exact results.

Using $y_1(t)$ at $t=1$, we have:

- $y_1(t) = \dfrac{1}{8} (-2 t+\sin(2 t)+6 \cos(2 t)+2)$, so
  $$y_1(1) = \dfrac{1}{8}(\sin 2 + 6 \cos 2)$$
- $y'_1(t) = \dfrac{1}{4} (-6 \sin(2 t)+\cos(2 t)-1)$, so
  $$y'_1(1) = \dfrac{1}{4}(-1 - 6 \sin 2 + \cos 2)$$

The general solution for $y_2(t)$ is:

$$y_2(t) = c_1 \cos(2 t) + c_2 \sin(2 t)+ \dfrac{t}{4}-\dfrac{1}{4}$$

The derivative of this is:

$$y'_2(t) = -2 c_1 \sin(2 t)+2 c_2 \cos(2 t)+ \dfrac{1}{4}$$

If we use $y_1(1)$ and $y'_1(1)$ as the initial conditions to solve for the constants of $y_2(t)$, we arrive at:

$$y_2(t) = \dfrac{1}{8} (2 t+ 2 \sin(2-2 t)+\sin(2 t)+6 \cos(2 t)-2)$$

I will assume you can handle the rest.

Comment: @user119709: Did you get it? Please recall to upvote and/or accept helpful answers. Regards

Comment: Good work! :-{+

Comment: @B.S.: Like your new Avatar!

Comment: @Amzoti: Thanks and Regards.

Comment: @B.S.: You are always welcome my friend!

Comment: @Amzoti: Thank you. But I'm stuck at the part of finding the constant at y2 solution. From using y1(1)=y2(1) I get A=3/4 and B=2/4 (same constants as for y1). But then y1'(1) doesn't  equal y2'(1). Maybe I wasn't clear at the first message, bus this is my primary problem here.